# MonoDevelop with Unity 2018.3.1 and .NET 4.X

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop

I don't know if there are still people who use MonoDevelop with Unity, but I love it and not willing to switch to visual studio.

I downloaded MonoDevelop for unity since it's not built in with unity and used it with no problems so far, however, since I updated my project to use .NET 4.X from unity's player settings (Scripting runtime version) MonoDevelop stopped working well. It does open my script and I edit them with no problems, but autocomplete doesn't work anymore at all and the syntax highlighting is barely there with only object type name is in one color and everything else is in white. I used a syntax highlighting called Monokai which I'm absolutely in love with.

How can I fix MonoDevelop to work with .NET 4.X because when I tried to change the Scripting runtime version from the player settings everything worked as expected with MonoDevelop

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can actually. As [this Unity blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/01/05/discontinuing-support-for-monodevelop-unity-starting-in-unity-2018-1/) states:

> On Windows, we ship Visual Studio 2017 Community with Unity and it already supports the latest C# features and C# debugging on the new .NET 4.6 scripting runtime. MonoDevelop-Unity 5.9.6 will be removed from the Unity 2018.1 Windows installer, as it does not support these features.

There may be some way of doing it, but I don't think it would be worth the trouble. There are plenty of other IDEs other than Visual Studio out there. I personally used [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) for a long time before switching to [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and finally back to Visual Studio proper.

Comment: From what I understand from this page https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/ .NET 4.6 is supported, or is it?

Comment: [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/) and [MonoDevelop](https://www.monodevelop.com/) are two different projects (Mono being a .Net Framework and MonoDevelop a IDE).

Comment: @user3182651 as MightyPotato pointed out support for MonoDevelop is dropped. The link you provided is for the mono framework, which is the actual scripting language, MonoDevelop is an IDE that offered support for the Framework. But the two are compeltely seperate things

Comment: Unity was maintaining MonoDevelop 5.x, which was very old and that's why it was finally dropped in favor of other modern options. MonoDevelop 7.x/8.x might still work for Windows (I started to maintain its installer), but I don't think I will be able to include Unity support, because that's too much effort.